# Mouse wheel (zoom) on canvas img

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

React beginner here, i have a canvas where is img, i wanted to implement zooming when user takes mouse on the picture then user could zoom in and out using mouse wheel,
i implemented it correctly because now zoom in and zoom out is possible but got one problem, img becomes smaller (but zooming works), if i remove 'TransformComponent' then img becomes bigger(as it should be this size) but user cannot zoom anymore.

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes
.

```js
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";


renderPreview() {
    const camera = this.props.currentCamera;

    // render size (not display size) of the canvas
    const canvasRenderWidth = camera
      ? camera.width
      : this.state.config.previewStyle.width;
    const canvasRenderHeight = camera
      ? camera.height
      : this.state.config.previewStyle.height;
    // display size of the canvas
    let canvasStyle = {
      width: canvasRenderWidth >= canvasRenderHeight ? "100%" : "auto",
      height: canvasRenderHeight > canvasRenderWidth ? "100%" : "auto",
    };
    return (
      <div style={this.state.config.previewStyle}>
        <TransformWrapper
       
        >
          <TransformComponent>
            <canvas
              ref="CameraPreviewCanvas"
              width={canvasRenderWidth}
              height={canvasRenderHeight}
              onClick={this.onClickCanvas}
              onMouseMove={this.onMouseOverCanvas}
              style={canvasStyle}
            ></canvas>
          </TransformComponent>
        </TransformWrapper>

        <img
          ref="CameraPreviewImage"
          src={this.state.snapshot.snapshotUrl}
          style={{ display: "none" }}
        ></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

img:

[image]

i want img width to be 100% as it is without 'TransformComponent'

any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Any help/suggestion is appreciated

Comment: The canvas is kind of its own thing and its content has really nothing to do with the DOM. So rather than trying to make a virtual DOM framework manage it, grab a reference to the canvas element as your component mounts, and then hand that over to a utility function that lives outside of React and adds normal plain JS event listening?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans why 'TransformComponent' makes img smaller ? if i remove that then canvas works fine except i dont get zooming functionality. Is there some css trick for example to stretch the img so that it would fill that area ?

Comment: Because that's its job? If you're talking about https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch at least. It uses CSS to achieve zoom/pan which is fine for image elements, but a pretty terrible idea for canvas, which uses a completely separate rendering system. To transform content in the canvas, use canvas functions (either the canvas API itself, or utility functions specifically written for canvas)

Comment: if i replace that with another, could you suggest some easy way to implements simple zoom in/out with mouse wheel/pinch with canvas working ?

Comment: there's nothing "easy" about canvas transforms, so: what are you _actually_ trying to achieve that makes you think you need a canvas element?